# How to use routing in angular 2 for query string parameter URL

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

directly access query string parameter URL in angular 2. 
Ex: https://www.example.com?user=johndoe&token=somevalue.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router <- read the docs

Comment: I followed as per the document in my local environment works. But in server it redirect to index.html not particular router component

Comment: So provide a [mcve] to recreate your specific problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Routing is a useful concept of Angular. First read about it carefully and then try to implement it.

You can read this link: https://coryrylan.com/blog/introduction-to-angular-routing

Comment: Yeah, I checked fine. Thanks

Comment: If this solution is useful for You, then mark this as a correct so that others can follow this if they faced same issues.